# How would I point a char to the memory address of a character in a NSString?

Tags: iphone, memory, nsstring, char, memory-address

I have an NSString *string = "HELLO". How would I get the address in memory of the letter E and point a char to it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how `NSString`s work; they're objects, and behave as such. I don't know if you can get addresses directly from them, but that would be a bad idea. Can you use a C-style string?

```
char *string = "HELLO";
char *letterE = string + 1;
```

If not, you can [convert between the two](http://www.wmdeveloper.com/2010/03/objective-c-convert-c-style-string-to.html):

```
char *cString = [string UTF8String]; // Or any encoding
```

P.S. I believe you mean (or should use) `@"HELLO"` in your example; `"HELLO"` is a C-style string.

Comment: Would letterE have it's own value (E) in memory or would it be pointing to the E in HELLO's location in memory

Answer (score 0):

You can't. An `NSString` object's memory is read-only and opaque; internal pointers are meaningless in this context. What is it you're trying to accomplish? There may be another way to do it (such as using an `NSMutableString`, or an array of `unichar` or `char` values.)

Answer (score 0):

You *can* use UTF8String, cStringUsingEncoding: or getCString:maxLength:encoding: to obtain a "C string" from the NSString, but the returned string has a (short) life of its own and is not tied to the character buffer in the NSString.

And, of course, the phrase "point a char to it" is meaningless.